# Binding issue ActualWidth on dynamic filled Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, actualwidth

Consider the following, simple code:

---

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Height="60" Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="162*" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="coltest" Width="316*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="239*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
<Label MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick" 
    Content="{Binding ElementName=coltest, Path=ActualWidth}" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

**The `MouseDoubleClick` event:**

```
private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Label l = new Label { Content = r.Next(10, 1000000000).ToString() };
        grid.Children.Add(l);
        Grid.SetRow(l, grid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(l, i);
    }
}
```

---

My label contains the `ActualWidth` property of the second column via a binding. In Visual Studio I see my label containing the value 316, so the binding works.

Double clicking the label triggers its event and adds an extra row to the grid, all with a random length.

I expect to see a new value at my label, but (the at runtime calculated) 0 does not change!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that `ActualWidth` of a `ColumnDefinition` isn't a Dependency Property, nor does it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the `Binding` has no way of knowing that the `ActualWidth` of coltest has changed.

You'll need to explicitly update the `Binding`

**Edit2:** In this case, you might be able to update the `Binding` in the `SizeChanged` event for the `Grid` since the `Columns` have `*` width. This won't work 100% with `Auto` width though since the width will change based on the elements in the `ColumnDefinition`

```
<Grid Name="grid"
      SizeChanged="grid_SizeChanged">
    <!--...-->
</Grid>
```

*Event handler*

```
void grid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    BindingExpression be = label.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
    be.UpdateTarget();
}
```

**Edit:** Made some small changes to the Xaml. This will update the `Binding` everytime you doubleclick the first `Label`

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="162*" />
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="coltest" Width="316*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="239*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="239*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label MouseDoubleClick="TextBox_MouseDoubleClick"
           Name="label"
           Content="{Binding ElementName=coltest, Path=ActualWidth}" Grid.Row="0"/>
</Grid>
```

*Event handler*

```
private void TextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; i++)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Label l = new Label { Content = r.Next(10, 1000000000).ToString() };
        grid.Children.Add(l);
        Grid.SetRow(l, grid.RowDefinitions.Count - 1);
        Grid.SetColumn(l, i);
    }
    BindingExpression be = label.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty);
    be.UpdateTarget();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I understand. How can I update the binding? It depends on when the ActualWidth property is calculated right?

Comment: Sure thing, glad I was able to help out :)

Comment: I actually had to listen to the `LayoutUpdated` event. The `SizeChanged` event was only triggered at initialization.

Comment: Well, the `SizeChanged` event is raised everytime the `Grid` changes size, but if you add a new `ColumnDefinition` for example, the `Grid` size won't change but the `ColumnDefinitions` of the `Grid` will. `LayoutUpdated` is raised on every update of the layout (size change or whatnot) so yes, no chance of missing the update there:)