# Can a mathematical operator be applied to the Binding path?

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, binding, converters

Can I have the following (the `ActualWidth` divided by 2)?

```
<StackPanel Name="SP2" Width="{Binding ElementName=SP1, Path=ActualWidth/2}">
```

Doesn't seem to work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Get `Width` set to half the value of `SP1.ActualWidth`? If so, a `Converter` is probably what you're after.

Comment: Please don't use `ActualWidth` in bindings, as it's not a dependency property and won't necessarily do what you expect. See questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403151 (WPF) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602148 (Silverlight).

Comment: @PhilipKendall, yes that was what I was trying to do.  I want SP2 to be half the width of SP1 every time the window is resized.

Comment: Place the two stack panels inside a two column grid, with column widths "2* and "*" respectively

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use a custom converter to perform simple calculations directly in XAML.

Take a look, for example, at this implementation:

[`MathConverter`](http://www.ikriv.com/en/prog/code/wpf/MathConverter/index.shtml)

Simple usage:

```
<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Text, ElementName=Seconds,
    Converter={ikriv:MathConverter}, ConverterParameter=x*6}" />
```

---

The classical approach is to create a readonly calculated property.
So in this simple case you can add a second property `HalfWidth`.

```
public double HalfWidth
{
    get
    {
        return ActualWidth / 2.0;
    }
}
```

The bad news is that when `ActualWidth` is updated, the `StackPanel` on the view bound to `HalfWidth` will not update.
This is because the view does not know that `HalfWidth` has changed.

By raising a property changed event on `HalfWidth` in the setter of `ActualWidth`, the view will query `HalfWidth` and hence retrieve the correct value.

```
private double _actualWidth;
public double ActualWidth
{
    get
    {
        return _actualWidth;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_actualWidth != value)
        {
            _actualWidth = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ActualWidth");
            OnPropertyChanged("HalfWidth");
        }
    }
}
```

The main proplem about this approach is that it will soon become a nightmare when we have numerous calculated properties with no setters.

That's why (in a MVVM pattern) I personally prefer to use a custom converter.

Comment: Thanks. How would one decide whether to go through all this effort or to just have one line in the Windows's SizeChanged event handler in code behind?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only use properties (and indexes into arrays/collections in some cases) in bindings.

Instead you need to either bind to a notify property that returns the intended value (e.g. ActualWidth/2), or use a converter that returns a value with your calculation applied.