# How can i get the ActualWidth of Grid.Column, after changing its width using *?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

In my c# wpf code i used to change programmaticaly the width of a grid column, like this :

```
 mycolumn.Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star);
```

But later in code, when i try to get the "ActualWidth", at first time, the value of ActualWidth (that is in pixel) it's always 0. The value is updated later by the parent window, for some reason i don't know.

```
double myWidthInPixels = myColumn.ActualWidth;
```

myWidthInPixels is set to 0, for the first time i ask it.

How to solve?

Comment: check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403151/binding-issue-actualwidth-on-dynamic-filled-grid

Answer (score -1):

The solution for me was this :

```
double myWidthInPixels = Convert.ToDouble(myColumn.GetValue(WidthProperty));
```

Comment: `new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star).ToString()` gives me `*` and `Convert.ToDouble(myColumn.Width)` throws

Comment: This is not what I wrote in my reply.  Check the conversion

Comment: `        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="col1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="col2"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>
` and `var pixel = System.Convert.ToDouble(col1.GetValue(WidthProperty));` did not give me the width in pixel but NAN

Comment: You set it to NAN ! Give width a value!

Comment: i set it to 1 star as in the question but in xaml.